# Error RecognitionConfig must either be unspecified or match the value in the FLAC header audio in google speech to text api

Tags: google-app-engine, speech-recognition, speech, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I already tried to transform the audio from stereo to mono, but not success, 
 I tried to change the rate in hertz, but without success too

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech
import os, logging 
import urllib.request

KEY_API_ROOT = 'path'
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]=KEY_API_ROOT+"xx.json"
client = speech.SpeechClient()

url = incoming_message['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['attachments'][0]['payload']['url']

if '.aac' in url:
    formato = 'aac'
else:
    formato = 'mp4'

# download audio
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, VOICE_ROOT + fbid + "." + formato)

# path
diretorio_audio = VOICE_ROOT + fbid + "." + formato

mp4_version = AudioSegment.from_file(diretorio_audio, formato)

mp4_version.export(VOICE_ROOT + fbid + ".flac", format="flac", bitrate="400k", parameters=["-ac", "1"])

with open(VOICE_ROOT + fbid + '.flac', 'rb') as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()

audio = speech.types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

config = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
    sample_rate_hertz=44100,
    language_code='en-US',
    enable_word_confidence=True)
try:
    response = client.recognize(config, audio)
except Exception as erro_stt:
    logging.info("Erro 66 ProcessarAudio no STT: {}".format(erro_stt))
```

Error:

> 400 sample_rate_hertz (44100) in RecognitionConfig must either be unspecified or match the value in the FLAC header (48000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with:

## Install packages

sudo apt-get install sox

sudo apt-get install libsox-fmt-mp3

## Execute

sox input.mp3 --rate 16k --bits 16 --channels 1 output.flac